# How to insert PDF table data into database

Tags: python, django, pdf-extraction, python-camelot

I have extracted pdf table data by using Camelot but now how can I do put my table data into my database like do I need to convert it into CSV?  like is there any other way to put it into my database? and is there any other way to choose my specific tables or just put the number of the tables. cause in here I need to specify my table no. to be extracted.

```py
def tables_extract(file_name):
    filename_with_path = 'upload/media/pos/pdfs/{}'.format(file_name)
    tables = camelot.read_pdf(filename_with_path, pages="1-end")
    table= tables[2].df
```

> **Below is the table data in the pdf  which I want to put the values into my DB**

[image]

Comment: Please describe your DB and what you tried.

Comment: @Anakin87 Mysql, actually I have converted the pdf into text using pdfminer and then extract some specific data through regular expression and put it into my database but um confuse about the tubular data as u can see I use Camelot to get into the table and now how to get the data and stored into my database. I'm confused about how to do that.